# Using InstallShield Limited Edition, how do I remove the uninstall dialog that requires a reboot

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, installshield-le

I am creating an installer for a web application and using InstallShield Limited Edition.  I can install just fine, but when I run the 'uninstall', I get a dialog box that says that a reboot is required.  However, all that I'm doing is deleting a folder.

How do I update the installer so that this dialog is not displayed upon uninstalling?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the following dialog ("FilesInUse" on XP and "MsiRMFilesInUse" on Vista) ? Note this is shown automatically by Windows Installer during the InstallValidate standard action when the installer checks if any file is in use and if so, it displays that dialog.
So, make sure you are not trying to delete some files which are in use.